# Cloud Run deployment using image from last revision

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-container-registry

We need to deploy labels to multiple `CLoud Run` services using below `API method`

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/replaceService

We are looking for options where we can apply `labels` using `API` without any new image deployment from `Container Registry` . We understand that there will be `deployment` and `revision change` while applying `labels` but we want that during deployment it should not pull new image from `container registry` rather it should use the image from `last revision` . Any configuration parameter in `Cloud Run` to prevent new images being pulled while applying labels using `API` or `gcloud run services update SERVICE --update-labels KEY=VALUE`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The principle of Cloud Run (and Knative, because the behavior is the same) is that the revision is immutable. Thus, if you change something in it, a new revision is created. You can't fake it!

So, the solution is to not use the latest tag of your image, but the SHA of it.

```
# the latest
gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/myImage
gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/myImage:latest

# A specific version
gcr.io/PROJECT_ID/myImage:SHA123465465dfsqfsdf
```

Of course, you have to update your YAML for this.

Comment: Since SHA numbers are random so how we can predict or fetch the SHA code of the image if it is created newly and pass it to the Cloud run for creating new revision. Could you please advise ?

Comment: You can define your own tag on the same image. You can use SHA, you can use v1.0.2, you can use string (latest, prod, test,...) what you want. The SHA is, most of the time, the commit SHA which is reused to make the link between the git source repo and your build. It's up to you to manage the tags smartly

Comment: I have a scenario where we are creating cloud run service which pulls the image from GCR with the image name . As of now in the cloud run we didn't specify that it should look for any specific tagged images. Now we wanted to create the new revision of the cloud run whenever there is a new image in the GCR. Since cloud run works by resolving the tag into SHA code , so even when we create new image , cloud run service is running on old image only.

Comment: If you don't specify the tag in Cloud Run service, the LATEST tag is used. Don't forget to tag your most recent image with LATEST to allow Cloud Run to get it when you redeploy the service.